# How can I find a hidden folder?

Tags: unix

I'm trying to find the hidden folder .uncrustify but I don't know where it is. How can I find this folder? I'm trying to do the following but I can't find the hidden folder .uncrustify

```
Examine the example config files in etc and/or read
documentation/htdocs/configuration.txt.
Copy the existing config file that closely matches your style and put in
~/.uncrustify/.  Modify to your liking.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `~` in `~/.uncrustify/` means your home directory. For example, if your Unix username is "lampshade", then the full path is likely to be `/home/lampshade/.uncrustify/`, but many programs accept the short form too.

If the directory does not exist, **create it**.

Answer (score 1):

It's in your home folder?

Comment: is that really a question?

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
sudo find / -name .uncrustify
```

Answer (score 0):

```
ls -lR |grep .uncrustify
```

but you also might want to 'cd' to your root if you want to scan your whole computer

```
cd /
```